# productsRequest not called in subclass

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subclass, skscene

The original in-app purchase codes's **working fine in a SKScene**, now I'm trying to place them in a subclass, other methods can be called, and `SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()` can be called, but `productsRequest` cannot be called. I moved the codes back to SKScene, it worked again.

Did I miss something in subclass?

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class Purchase: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

......

 func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

        print("in product request")

        var products = response.products
        if (products.count > 0) {
            for i in 0 ..< products.count
            {
                if products[i].productIdentifier == buyingProduct{
                    buyProduct(products[i])
                    break
                }
            }

        } else {
            print("No products found")

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing ... did you assign this subclass as the new delegate for SKProductsRequestDelegate?

Comment: I did not set SKProductsRequestDelegate in SKScene. Did you mean that I should assign SKProductsRequestDelegate in SKScene?